# xamarin.forms xaml value cannot be null parameter name: type

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I wanted to Build my Project like every day, but now I cannot Build the project because I get the following error message in every .xaml File:

```
the value cannot be null.
parameter name: type
```

What can I do?

I deleted my bin/obj Folders in Portable and iOS Project, but nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: Some of your recent change in XAML is causing this check if you assigning something incorrectly make sure you have XAML complication active in your xaml.cs

Comment: How can I check, which File and Line of Code causing the error ?
XAML complication is active.

Comment: Add a try-catch to your constructor's initialize component method that should get you al you need if its not happening at compile time

Comment: The problem occurs if I want to Build my Portable Project.
So I cant add an try catch around InitializeComponent.

Comment: Okay, cool so it's a compile-time error when you double click where does it take you?

Comment: to the first line in the xaml code and that for every single file.
I got 44 files with this error.

Comment: Oh ok, your vs version? Have you tried restarting?

Comment: I got the vs professional 2019 version wit the latest vs update 16.5.1.
Xamarin.forms version is 4.5.0.495.
I tried restarting VS, my PC and cleaning PCL-Project and iOS Project but nothing works.

Comment: Added an answer below take a look

Comment: Does you make any change before it can't Build?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug of this on [Xamarin's Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4678)

Following is what helped some people solve this issue:

> I've experienced an issue when Xamarin builds changes between Android and iOS. It might be possible to workaround by the following sequence:
>
> - Select your iOS project as the startup.
> - Make sure the Android project is NOT selected to be built in config management.
> - Clean solution.
> - Quit VS.
> - Delete bin & obj from XAML project and from the iOS project.
> - Restart VS.
> - Build XAML and iOS projects.

There are more workarounds that you might check if this does not work

Comment: Okay, now I disable or deleted all XAMLC.
Now, I can create my project. But when I add in one XAML-Page the XAMLC, I get the error again, but nothing is wrong in my XAML.